# How do i deploy from GitLab CI to Google Container Engine instance using Docker?

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, docker-machine, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to set up automated deployment using a GitLab CI runner to deploy our 4-container app via `docker-compose`. I can pull the container images down using `docker pull` commands, but I'm stuck on how to connect to the Google Compute Engine instance in order to run the full `docker-compose` script.

Typically, from my local machine, I run something like:

```
eval $(docker-machine env <machine-instance>)
docker-compose up -d
```

But my `.gitlab-ci.yml` script doesn't have `docker-machine` available.

1. Do I have to install `docker-machine` via the `script` section in my
   `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?
2. How do I provision the instance without
   creating a new one every time? Normally, from my local host, I would
   run `docker-machine create ...` once then just use the `eval`
   command above to reconnect to the instance. But how would this work
   with CI?

Here's a sample of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
deploy staging:
    image: docker:latest
    services:
        - docker:dind
    environment: staging
    stage: deploy
    before_script:
        - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN my-registry.githost.io
    script:
        - docker pull my-registry.githost.io/group/project1:develop
        - docker pull my-registry.githost.io/group/project2:develop
        - docker pull my-registry.githost.io/group/project3:develop
        - docker pull my-registry.githost.io/group/project4:develop
        - docker-machine ls
```

Comment: [This link](http://totallyon.me/2016/09/22/running-gitlab-ci-runner-in-gce/) might help. [Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/) has also a pre-configured GitLab version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need docker-machine for in this case. You might want to get rid of it.

But to go back to your question, the docker image you're using does not come with neither docker-machine, nor docker-compose :

https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/36e2107fb879d5d5c3dbb5d8d93aeef0a2d45ac8/1.12/Dockerfile

So you will need to create a new image (or find an existing one) that comes with those two installed.
So in the .gitlab-ci.yml, instead of `image: docker:latest`, it's going to be something like `image: mydocker`

Comment: Eventually i would like to use `docker-machine` to connect to my Google Compute Engine instance to deploy my app via the command: `eval $(docker-machine env <instance-name>)`.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe have to install docker-machine in the GitLab CI Runner to use it with GCE

https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/

https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/gce/